# How to make a JSON file localizable in iOS?

Tags: ios, json, localization

I have a JSON file containing a dictionary with strings in an iOS app. Our dev team sends off our app to a localization team via an .xliff file. Is JSON compatible with localization in iOS? Or should I convert it to some other file type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using the Apple-provided file type of .strings

Localization in iOS is actually really great. You have a .lproj folder for each language that you are using, prefixed by the [ISO 639-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes) language codes.

Within each of those folders, you can provide a .strings file that would contain all of the localized strings for that language.

For example, your en.lproj could have a "Localizable.strings" file as follows:

```
"Hello" = "Hello";

"World = "World";
```

And your es.lproj (Spanish) could have a "Localizable.strings" file as follows:

```
"Hello" = "Hola";

"World" = "Mundo";
```

You would then start using NSLocalizedString for all of your user-facing strings throughout your app. It might take a bit of leg-work to get started, but it is a very helpful system that is already built-in. Take a look at [NSHipster's NSLocalized String](http://nshipster.com/nslocalizedstring/) entry for a good read about how this works and how it might benefit you.

*Links valid as of July 30, 2015*