# How to translate app in to another language in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, localization, internationalization

I am developing an ecommerce app. Initially the app is in the English language and now I want to convert it into the Chinese and French language. I referred to [this link](https://www.raywenderlich.com/64401/internationalization-tutorial-for-ios-2014)

So what I have understood is that every text we need to convert into French and Chinese, in the respective string files for the static data, but I am getting data from the backend. So then how do I convert that text dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code. And in Project you can add localisations in info.plist.Hope it will help you.Thank You

```
  NSLocale* curentLocale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
 namearray=[NSMutableArray   arrayWithObjects:NSLocalizedString(@"Hellokey1",@""),NSLocalizedString(@"Hellokey2",@""),NSLocalizedString(@"Hellokey3",@""),NSLocalizedString(@"Hellokey4",@""),NSLocalizedString (@"Hellokey5",@""),NSLocalizedString(@"Hellokey6",@""),NSLocalizedString(@"Hellokey7",@""),NSLocalizedString(@"Hellokey8",@""),NSLocalizedString(@"Hellokey9",@""),NSLocalizedString(@"Hellokey10",@""),NSLocalizedString(@"Hellokey11",@""),NSLocalizedString(@"Hellokey12",@""),NSLocalizedString(@"Hellokey13",@""),NSLocalizedString(@"Hellokey14",@""),NSLocalizedString(@"Hellokey15",@""),NSLocalizedString(@"Hellokey16",@""),NSLocalizedString(@"Hellokey17",@""),NSLocalizedString(@"Hellokey18",@""),NSLocalizedString(@"Hellokey19",@""),NSLocalizedString(@"Hellokey20",@""),NSLocalizedString(@"Hellokey21",@""),NSLocalizedString(@"Hellokey22",@""),NSLocalizedString(@"Hellokey23",@""),NSLocalizedString(@"Hellokey24",@""),NSLocalizedString(@"Hellokey25",@""),NSLocalizedString(@"Hellokey26",@""),NSLocalizedString(@"Hellokey27",@""),nil];

  [curentLocale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleIdentifier
                          value:[curentLocale localeIdentifier]];
// NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"fr" ofType:@"lproj"];
// NSLog(@"path:%@",path);
  NSString *language = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] preferredLocalizations] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: @kaur by using the above code it will apply to dynamic data?

Comment: I am using this for static data.

Comment: is there any alternative for dynamic ?

Comment: You can change array from json into NSLocalizedstring

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31730639/how-to-make-a-json-file-localizable-in-ios...You can see this link..hope i will help you

Answer (score 0):

If the text received is truly dynamic (i.e. there's no way to know ahead of time what the possible variations are), there's no way to do it.  If you know what the possibilities are, you embed the translations just as you do for static text, and you have the server send the localization key.  This is the scheme used by iOS for translating notification alerts.

(You could theoretically use a translation API, such as Google Translate, but that has many downsides, and few upsides.)